# How is the operator !! in R package rlang being defined?

Tags: r, operator-keyword, rlang

I've only learned how to define an operator as infix function that wrapped in `%%` in R such as the most commonly used pipe operator `%>%` from Hadley Wickham's book Advanced R, however how the operators `!!` and `!!!` are defined in package `rlang` is not mentioned in the book, and the code `View(rlang::!!)` only returns result like this:

```
function (x) 
{
  abort("`!!` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument")
}
```

So could anyone tell me how to define operators like this in R, thanks in advance!

Comment: They are actually in chapter 19 of that book. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting

Comment: I know this, but this only tells me how to use this operator, I wonder how it is defined, or how to access its source code.

Comment: Got it. I don't think they are actually defined as operators. They are interpreted by the whole `tidyeval` structure. So it's not that `!!` has a definition and the R interpreter knows what to do with it, its that the rlang knows what to do when it sees it (hence the message that it can only be used within a quasiquoted argument). I am not an expert on that and probably butchered it, but that is my general understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I still wonder how to define my own operators like `!!` that are not wrapped in `%%` when I write a package.

Comment: I think you have to build your own [parsing function](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/master/src/internal/parse.c) in C to do that.